# Codeigniter not load model?

Tags: codeigniter

Hello friends i used hmvccodeigniter and this is my controller file code.

filename = settings.php

```
class Settings extends Controller {
    function addsetting()
    {

      $this->load->model('setting_model');
      $this->setting_model->addsetting_model();
    }
}
```

this is my model file code.

filename = setting_model.php

```
class Setting_model extends Model {
     function addsetting_model()
     {
        echo "come";
     }
}
```

the model file is not call. it's return 505 internal server error.

Comment: I think you should extend CI_Model, not Model and CI_Controller not Controller

Comment: check the version of the codigniter in earlier version Model class & in new version CI_Model please check the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyy,

You can add Setting_model into

> config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['model'] = array('Setting_model');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using third party extension for making codeginter HMVC, please refere its user manual and folllow proper steps. 
But if want any short thing go and check extended controller & model name, because if you are extending only "Controller & Model" (These are standard codeigniter classes) classes they are not support HMVC. 
So my suggestion is use like follow

```
class Settings extends My_Controller {
    function addsetting()
    {
```

&  for model

```
class Setting_model extends My_Model {
     function addsetting_model()
     {
```

My_Controller & My_Model may be different as per your extension, but check on only here.

Answer (score 0):

Model require with filename is all on lowercase.

But, the class name needs to be correct:

```
class Settings extends Controller {
    function addsetting()
    {
      $this->load->model('Setting_model');
      $this->Setting_model->addsetting_model();
    }
}
```